# What meaning does the word "respectively" add?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I do not understand what extra meaning does the word respectively add in a sentence.

Does it add meaning like "as in the order of the things mentioned"

For example:

> In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third respectively.

When we say :

> In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third in a row.

Does the meaning of the sentence change?

How can we rewrite this sentence?

Comment: Info here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/what-does-the-word-respectively-mean-in-software-development

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The word "respectively" verifies that the order in the first list corresponds to the order in the second list. So, in your example, Lizzy came in first and Sarah came in third.

We could leave the word out, but then the meaning wouldn't be 100% clear:

> In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third.

That sentence could mean that Lizzy came in first and Sarah came in third, or it could mean that Lizzy came in third and Sarah came in first. (I think the former is more likely, but the word "respectively" removes all doubt.)

In the case of the sentence in your comment:

> I bought a kitten, a bunny, and a puppy and named them Alfred, Bob, and Chuck respectively.

Yes, you can say that – it shows that your kitten is named Alfred, your bunny is named Bob, and your puppy is named Chuck.

Comment: Yep, the first option is much more likely to be assumed. In this specific case, respectively doesn't change the meaning much.  An alternate way would be to simply say *Lizzy came first and Sarah came third*, as you did in your explanation.

Comment: I *almost* CV'd as "Basic question on meaning that should be answered using a dictionary", but I'm sure this has been asked before more than once (here or on ELU, I dunno). So maybe it's a particularly awkward concept for learners (who may not have an equivalent in their own language). Anyway, it's a nice clear answer.

Comment: ...as opposed to *all* of them being named "Andrew Bob Chuck", presumably.

Comment: Also useful if the elements of one list do not necessarily uniquely match the elements of the other list: "Fred and Sally had a water and a cola, respectively", meaning Fred had a water and Sally had a cola. Replace "respectively" with "each", and both people had two drinks. Use neither, and the meaning is totally ambiguous.

Comment: How about this sentence : "countries which use the least mobile phones are A, B , C and D respectively." I mean here the country A uses the least relatively.

Comment: @Murat That would be an incorrect use as you've not got two lists to compare.  Instead, you would say something like *Countries which use the fewest mobile phones are A, B, C and D with A using the fewest.* or, *Countries which use the least mobile phones are, in increasing order, A, B, C and D.*

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Not really. If I simply say, _I bought a kitten, a bunny, and a puppy and named them Alfred, Bob, and Chuck_, you don't know for sure which animal got which name. So I'd say it's more like "...as opposed to the kitten being named Chuck and the puppy being named Alfred," or something like along those lines.

Comment: Not mentioned, but there is a particular advantage to this format over "Countries which use the least mobile phones are, in increasing order, A, B, C, and D" which may be of interest here.  "Respectively" comes at the end of the sentence, and you can put a pause in the sentence before that word.  Often a speaker will believe it is very clear that they are discussing topics in order, but only at the end of the sentence realize that it was not as clear as intended.  In these cases, "respectively" at the end of the sentence is an excellent chance to resolve this unintended confusion.

Comment: @CortAmmon: You could always say "*Countries which use the fewest mobile phones are A, B, C and D, in increasing order.*" The phrase "in this/that order" also works, if there's already an implied order, as in "*The first people to arrive were A, B and C, in that order.*" Using "respectively" for this, however, is IMO just plain meaningless, since there is no other list to establish a correspondence with.

Answer (score 6):

[J.R.'s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/52195/4468) has already covered "respectively" and I don't think there's anything to add, there.

> In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third in a row.

This doesn't actually make sense. "In a row" refers to doing the same thing on multiple consecutive occasions.  For example, "Lizzy came first five times in a row" means that she won five races consecutively.  It doesn't make sense to say "in a row" on its own unless you mean "physically arranged in a line", as in "Lizzy put her five gold medals in a row on the table."